Nipype installation
Summary
Can't install nipype using docker.
Surely I misunderstand something on how to run the program.
Actual behavior
When I try to run nipype using docker run -p 8888:8888 nipype/nipype or docker run --rm -it -p 8888:8888 nipype/nipype I've got the following error : INFO: /home/neuro/matlab/startup.m does not exist ... creating
I also tried with docker run -p 8888:8888 nipype/nipype jupyter notebook or docker run --rm -it -p 8888:8888 nipype/nipype jupyter notebook
How to replicate the behavior

pull the Docker image docker pull nipype/nipype
run the image docker run -p 8888:8888 nipype/nipype

Platform details:
I'm using Docker 26.1.2 and I tried on both Linux and Windows.
